# Kotlin - [daemon] Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1g -Xshare:off

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

After updating IntelliJ and pulling the newest code from the repo for my project, I keep getting build errors like `Kotlin: Unresolved reference`, `Kotlin: Too many arguments for public fun`, etc., that I wasn't getting before.

I am trying to run `Reload All Gradle Projects` through IntelliJ, but then I keep getting the following error:

```
[daemon] Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1g -Xshare:off
```

I was able to build project fine for the past few months, but now when I have pulled the latest from the remote repo I keep getting that error when I try to `Reload All Gradle Projects`.
This is how my `gradle.properties` file looks like:

```
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512M -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -Xshare:off -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx1g -Xshare:off"
org.gradle.logging.level=lifecycle
org.gradle.console=auto
```

Since it is a part of our git repo, I am afraid to do any changes there. I have read that it could be an issue with having 32 bit JDK instead of the 64 bit, but I have the right version:

```
openjdk version "17.0.3" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.3+7 (build 17.0.3+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.3+7 (build 17.0.3+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Even if I comment out the `org.gradle.jvmargs` in `gradle.properties` file, I get build errors:

```
Redeclaration: Glow_kotlinAppConventionsPlugin
```

I have tried to run `./gradlew clean` from terminal as well, but that didn't help.

I have also increased the `Shared build process heap size` from `1400` to `4000 Mbytes` in `IntelliJ -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler`. That didn't help either.

I have tried with going through IntelliJ's `Repair IDE` steps, but that gave me the same errors when I was trying to rebuild project.

I am running out of ideas, how can I solve this issue and why has it all of a sudden appeared?

Comment: I doubt you have multiple jdk versions installed since "java -version" gets only the active one. Which OS do you have? for example for linux, please try to use: "sudo update-alternatives --config java" to test if there is more than one jdk installed in the machine

Comment: Also please ensure that the project is using this mentioned jdk not the one comes with intellij out of the box

Comment: I checked project jdk and it is the same version as the one I get in the terminal. Also I am using Mac OS.

Comment: What happens when you try "invalidate cache and restart" from the file menu?

Comment: Separate arguments with commas (,) or remove spaces in -Xmx1g -Xshare:off

Answer (score 6):

The error message

```
[daemon] Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1g -Xshare:off
```

seems to show that option was not parsed properly.
In the doc: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#setting-kotlin-daemon-s-jvm-arguments
it says:

```
Separate arguments with commas (,) without spaces...
```

Answer (score -1):

Change from

```
 -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx1g -Xshare:off"
```

to

```
-Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx1g"
```

JVM doesnt know what is Xshare

Comment: Xshare is documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/vm/class-data-sharing.html#GUID-EC975B2E-B4AB-45B4-B91F-51C3A264D0CE

Answer (score -1):

Please verify whether your windows version is 32-bit or 64-bit, and download the correct version of JAVA. ([JAVA VERSION](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-windows))

`-Xms64m or -Xms64M`   // 64 megabytes

`-Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options= "-Xmx1g"` or -Xmx1G     //(1 GB)

Modify the -Xmx parameter to use anything <=2g